# html5 video end screen (youtube style)

Tags: javascript, php, html5-video

I currently embed content on a website i am developing using html 5 video tags. What I am looking to try and achieve is presenting the viewer with an end screen like youtube does offering other videos for them to watch(ideally the next in the series of tutorials). I have had success in redirecting the whole screen to another page using javascript and the event listener 'ended', but what I really want to do is simply offer links to the next or other relevant videos which the user can then click to navigate if they wish.

I have looked on google and stack overflow but everyone seems to be interested in providing a final image rather than a true end screen like youtube does.

Any assistance or ideas to help me develop this would be great.

Comment: Just pause the video at the last frame and put a div on top of it with the contents you want? Have you tried anything at all yet? Questions without any attempts (included in the question) are usually considered too unfocused here.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have posted an answer based on your thoughts below. Lets see if anyone comes up with something more sleek. The whole purpose of this was to get peoples thoughts rather than a bespoke answer and code to accompany it. But I take your point that I should perhaps have tried something first

Comment: That's not really how this site works. If the posted answer solves your issue, then you should accept it so other users can see it's been resolved. However, the question itself is still of low quality since it doesn't contain a specific issue with your current implementation, but rather a "How do I...", which isn't really on-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Magnus Ericsson comment.

I produced the following for any visitors to the post.

The below code waits for the ended event listener to fire then hides the video and shows the div. The idea being you fill the div with any relevant links and styling you require.

```
<style>
    .content-hide{
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<video id="video" width="100%" height="100%" controls>
   <source src="content/videos/<?php echo $posts['video_link']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
   <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="content/videos/<?php echo $posts['video_link']; ?>.vtt" default>
Your browser does not support video feeds from this website. Contact the website admin for assistance
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended',endscreenShow,false);
    
 function endscreenShow(e){
    var div = document.getElementById("vid-end-screen");
    var div1 = document.getElementById("video");
    div1.classList.add("content-hide");
    div.classList.remove("content-hide");
    div.innerHTML = "NEXT VIDEO LINKS / REPEAT VIDEO GO HERE";
 }
</script>
<div id="vid-end-screen" class="content-hide">I'm Hidden</div>
```